# Saving values for selection in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to build a shiny app for forecasting revenue for a company using Monte Carlo Simulation. This revenue is defined as Sel * Act * Siz * Rat. I will make the user input the min and max value for these 4 variables and hence calculate the AFYP(revenue).

Here is the code-

Server.R

```
    shinyServer(function(input, output) {

      getAFYP_round <- reactive({
set.seed=12345
options(scipen = 999)
Sel<-runif(10000, input$num1[1], input$num1[2])
Act<-runif(10000, input$num3[1], input$num3[2])
Siz<-runif(10000, input$num5[1], input$num5[2])
Rat<-runif(10000, input$num7[1], input$num7[2])

AFYP <- Sel*Act*Siz*Rat
AFYP
      })

    })
```

ui.R

```
    shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

      sidebarPanel(

selectInput(inputId="Tier", label="Choose Tier:",choices = list("Metro", "Urban", "Semi-Urban","Rural")),
selectInput(inputId="Designation", label="Choose Designation:",choices = list("Wealth", "Acquisition", "Service","Others")),
    "Choose the min & max value-",
        sliderInput("num1", "No of Sellers:",0,2000,value = c(800,1200),step=1),
        sliderInput("num3", "Activation Percentage:",0,1,value = c(0.4,0.6),step=0.01),
        sliderInput("num5", "Case Size:",0,50000,value = c(20000,30000),step=1),
        sliderInput("num7", "Case Rate:",0,3,value = c(1.2,1.8),step=0.01)
),


      mainPanel("",
                h1("Results for Monte Carlo Simulation")

    ))

    )
```

Now the task ahead I have is, for each combination of InputID, Tier and Designation, user should be able to enter the min and max value for the 4 variables used for calculating AFYP and these value should stay stored when ever the user comes back to the combination selection. I need to do this to calculate the overall AFYP for the company which will be the sum of AFYP generated for all possible combination of Tier and Designation.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you reduce your code on the minimal problem? This would make it much easier to help you.

Comment: Hey sorry about that. Done.

Comment: So you have 16 different combinations of Tier and Designation for which you want to store the 4 variables?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i want.